# Firebase call in Alexa skill being duplicated

Tags: node.js, firebase, alexa-skills-kit

I have the following handler:

```
'addTask': function () {
    var filledSlots = delegateSlotCollection.call(this);

    var taskName = this.event.request.intent.slots.taskName.value;
    var starNum = this.event.request.intent.slots.starNum.value;
    var usr = this.event.session.user.userId.split(".")[3];
    if (taskName && starNum && taskName !== "?" && starNum !=="?"){
        db.addTask(usr, taskName, parseInt(starNum), res => {
            this.emit(":tell", res);
        });
    }
},
```

All of the Firebase functions were tested through a input/output method and work as expected. This function is expected to push a new task to the database, or add to the quantity if such a task exists.

Here is the Firebase code;

```
addTask: (user, taskName, stars, cb) => {
    var ref = db.ref("users/" + user + "/tasks");
    ref.once("value").then(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.val();
        for (var task in data){
            if (data[task].name === taskName){
                ref.child(task).update({
                    name: taskName,
                    stars: stars,
                    quantity: data[task].quantity + 1
                }).then(() => {
                    cb("This task already exists, and an instance of the task has been added.");
                })
            }
        }
        ref.push().set({
            name: taskName,
            stars: stars,
            quantity: 1
        }).then(() => {
            cb("The task " + taskName + " worth " + stars + " stars has been added!");
        })
    }, err => console.log(err.code));
},
```

However, when using it through Alexa, it was found that the function was called twice (sometimes three times) at almost exactly the same time. However the Alexa simulator would only respond once, with the information of the second call (which would say that it added to the quantity).

Any idea how this is happening, or at least have a hacky solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

Turns out `if (taskName && starNum)` is not sufficient to ensure that it's the last time it calls the intent. A check to make sure `request.dialogState` is `"COMPLETED"` rather than `"IN_PROGRESS"` is required.